# Is there a bug in the ProgressMonitorDialog constructor?

Tags: java, swt, jface

When I go to create a new instance of a ProgressMonitorDialog, it ignores the internal shell style and setBlockOnOpen.  I'm not even sure how/why this would be happening.  The close button in the title bar does not work (which I consider a bug), but the cancel button works fine.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue or is something odd triggering it to behave differently?

My code:

```
ProgressMonitorDialog pmd = new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell);
pmd.run(true, true, new MyOperation());
```

Source code for Constructor:

```
public ProgressMonitorDialog(Shell parent) {
    super(parent);
    // no close button on the shell style
    if (isResizable()) {
        setShellStyle(getDefaultOrientation() | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE
                | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.RESIZE | SWT.MAX);
    } else {
        setShellStyle(getDefaultOrientation() | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE
                | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    }
    setBlockOnOpen(false);
}
```

What I see in the title bar:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly platform dependent (Mac, Linux, Windows...). Not all platforms support not having a close button and the best that can be done is to disable it.

Comment: I'm using Linux.  Good to know!